# Unity goes beyond a value set as limit, when using scrollwheel

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is rather bizarre; and I have no idea how to actually fix it.

I use a set of limit (min and max), to know how much the scrollwheel can zoom in or out a camera. The problem is that the camera get stuck, because I specify that the zoom should happen only if the y position is between min and max.

Unity always overshoot when using the mouse scrollwheel; if I set 1.0f, and scroll; the final result end up being 0.92; and same goes if I set a max of 5.0f, and using the scrollwheel, it overshoot to 5.1.

This result in the camera getting stuck, because now the camera y value is set beyond the limits, so obviously it won't move.

How do you actually avoid that Unity will go beyond the actual limits?

This is what I use

```
float mouse = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
float zoom_speed = 1.0f; 
if (transform.position.y <= 3f && transform.position.y >= 1f)
    transform.Translate(0, -mouse * zoom_speed, mouse * zoom_speed, Space.World);
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to limit? How far the camera moves when roll the scrollwheel?

Comment: Correct; so it won't clip trough things. I have a min and max height, so I can control how close or how far the camera is.

Comment: Just got back. Did Nika's answer work? I want to know if I need to provide answer or not.

Comment: I just noticed the change; trying it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

Basically if I go below or above the limit; I just set the limit by hand. Not elegant, but with 4 lines of code I get what I need.

I also did change how I handle the zoom; since I don't need to move on both Y and Z axis, I just lower the camera on Y axis, which works better for my scenario

```
float mouse = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
float zoom_speed = 1.0f; 

if (transform.position.y <= 3f && transform.position.y >= 1f)
    transform.Translate(0, -mouse * zoom_speed, 0);
    if (transform.position.y < 1f)
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1f, transform.position.z)
    if (transform.position.y > 3f)
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 3f, transform.position.z)
```

With this, the value get tweaked as soon as it is changed, it happens so fast that the camera does not jitter or even move slightly. Pretty sure there are better ways to do so, but this seems to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

So, this code makes your transform travel between minZoomPos and maxZoomPos in world space. The currentZoom is the normalized value that determines how close is transform to minZoomPos and how var from maxZoomPos:

```
Vector3 minZoomPos = new Vector3(0, 1f, -3f); //transform's position when zoomed in all the way
Vector3 maxZoomPos = new Vector3(0, 3f, -1f); //position when zoomed out
float currentZoom = 0f; //this is normalized value >> 0 means it's zoomed all the way in, 1 means it's on all the way out

float zoom_speed = 1.0f; //if you keep these declarations in Update() function it will give you unnecessary overhead on garbage collection

void Update(){
    currentZoom += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * zoom_speed;
    currentZoom = Mathf.Clamp01(currentZoom);

    //get point between minZoomPos and maxZoomPos depending on currentZoom
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (minZoomPos, maxZoomPos, currentZoom);
}
```

Comment: This is probably useful but can you add some information to explain what you've changed and why it helps?

Comment: what I did was try to translate the transform no matter what and then clamp y and z values between 1 and 3.

Comment: Do you use this in Update()? I get the screen continuously flashing; trying to change between min and max value, when running this code in Update. Removing the clamp on Z remove the flashing, but the camera does not move straight when zooming in and out

Comment: NP, trying it now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay;I did try it but there is a problem: if you zoom you can't move the camera at all, beside on the zoom axis. I use the mouse on the borders of the screen to move the camera; when you lerp the position the result is that the zoom works but the camera is locked in position no matter what,